# 1440p monitor work only as 440p (AMD Ryzen 5 7600 as GPU)

Tags: display-resolution, amd-graphics, monitor, wayland, amdgpu

I have troubles with my monitor resolution it only work in 440p. I install amdgpu drivers from AMD web site (I tried pro and open source). I use Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Monitor: Asus rog swift PG278Q (connected through DP)

Specs from CoreCtrl v1.4.0-dev:

```
==== Software ====
Kernel version: 6.1.4
Mesa version: 23.2.0

==== [GPU 0] ====
BIOS version: 102-RAPHAEL-006
Device ID: 164E
Device model ID: 8877
Driver: amdgpu
Memory: 512 MB
OpenGL version (compat): 4.6
OpenGL version (core): 4.6
PCI Slot: 0000:0b:00.0
Revision: C6
Vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Vendor ID: 1002
Vendor model ID: 1043
Vulkan API version: 4206842
```

I believe that problem with monitor because `get-edid` return thus (I tried this monitor with windows and it is working good)

```
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
Looks like no busses have an EDID. Sorry!
Attempting to use the classical VBE interface

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function unsupported
    Call failed

    VBE version 0
    VBE string at 0x0 "O"

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Report DDC capabilities

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function unsupported
    Call failed

Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Read EDID

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
    Function unsupported
    Call failed

The EDID data should not be trusted as the VBE call failed
Error: output block unchanged
I'm sorry nothing was successful. Maybe try some other arguments
```